# How to forward/integrate Discourse posts to/with Slack?

Tags: slack, slackbot, slack-integration

I would like to submit Discourse posts to a Slack channel.

When I googled the topic some old blog posts came up from 2016/17 for an integration that seems deprecated.

What's the recommended way to set this integration up nowadays?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks that this is something that should be done by an admin. It might be on-topic in  [webmasters.se]. If this will be done in business setting, it might also be on-topic in [sf].

Comment: HI Cornelius Roemer, FYI you could vote to reopen this question since you have more than 500 rep.

Answer (score 2):

For hosted instances this is quite easy, I was confused by the distinction between self-hosted and hosted.

If it's hosted one can simply follow this guide for general information about the *chat integration* (with a number of different partners, like Slack, Telegram, Microsoft Teams, Gitter, ...): https://meta.discourse.org/t/chatroom-integration-plugin-discourse-chat-integration/66522

For information specifically about how to set up the Slack side of things, follow this guide: https://meta.discourse.org/t/set-up-slack-notifications-using-the-discourse-chat-integration-plugin/66730

Following these manuals took me less than an hour, and the result is pleasing.

The links above should be stable, as Discourse updates the posts if the guide needs to change. The guides were posted in 2017 but are continuously edited.